# Need a better approach in how to design this relation

Tags: postgresql, database-design, relations

I have a table `fluxo`, and fluxo have many `fluxo_acao`, but a entry in `fluxo_acao` can have three types, and each type have they particularities. to acomplish this, i created more three tables(`fluxo_acao_mensagem`, `fluxo_acao_pergunta` and `fluxo_acao_escolher_fila`), connected to `fluxo_acao`.

The problem is i can't select any of the three tables, from `fluxo`, because first i need to check wich type is and them i do the query.

I need a better approach in how to acomplish this relation or connect `fluxo_acao` to the three tables. Even why i need create another two more. and this is the perfect time to change.

[image: fluxo]
[image: fluxo_acao]
[image: other three tables]

someone just told me [Inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-inheritance.html) may help me. i'm searching how.

Comment: What is a fluxo?

Comment: in this case is a table. in my system it's a flow and have many actions that follow a order in this flow

Comment: Please don't ask a question in multiple Stackexchange forums at the same time.

Comment: Sorry @LaurenzAlbe. Now i searched about [cross-posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) and find out that not allowed, but i can't delete the SO question now, so i linked this question there and voted to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I can't see exactly what your primary keys are, but it sounds like your issue isn't with subtypes themselves, but more likely the choice of primary key and path dependence.

So if `fluxo` has a primary key `id_fluxo`, and the relation to `fluxo_acao` is one to many AND duplicates aren't too tightly controlled, you can set up your primary key as:

1. `id_fluxo_acao` - bad, just a row pointer
2. `(id_fluxo, id_fluxo_acao)` - okay, still a row pointer but no notion of what is unique
3. `(id_fluxo, ordem)`  (flow, order?) - better, but per your comment it could update frequently and would require updates to the related subtype.
4. `(id_fluxo, timestamp)` - best, provides uniqueness and supplies valuable metadata

Then the primary key of each subtype will contain `id_fluxo` and you can join directly from `fluxo` to any of the subtypes.

Your comment:

> But lets say that i want to select all the entries in the three tables
> from fluxo how can i do this with joins. After addind this other pk in
> fluxo_acao

This you can do easily enough with a simple query that can be hardened into a view later:

```
SELECT
  fluxo.id_fluxo
 ,fluxo.descricao
 ,fluxo.id_status
 ,fluxo.data_criacao
 ,fluxo.id_empresa
 ,fluxo.tipo
 ,fluxo_acao.tipo AS acao_tipo
 ,fluxo_acao.timestamp
 ,fluxo_acao.ordem
 /* columns from each subtype */
FROM
  fluxo fluxo
INNER JOIN
  fluxo_acao fluxo_acao
    ON fluxo_acao.id_fluxo = fluxo.id_fluxo
LEFT JOIN
  fluxo_acao_mensagem fluxo_acao_mensagem
    ON fluxo_acao_mensagem.id_fluxo = fluxo_acao.id_fluxo
        AND fluxo_acao_mensagem.timestamp = fluxo_acao.timestamp /* Not sure what the Portuguese would be for "created at" or "CreateTimestamp" */
LEFT JOIN
  fluxo_acao_pergunta  fluxo_acao_pergunta 
    ON fluxo_acao_pergunta.id_fluxo = fluxo_acao.id_fluxo
        AND fluxo_acao_pergunta .timestamp = fluxo_acao.timestamp
LEFT JOIN
  fluxo_acao_escolher_fila  fluxo_acao_escolher_fila
    ON fluxo_acao_escolher_fila.id_fluxo = fluxo_acao.id_fluxo
        AND fluxo_acao_escolher_fila.timestamp = fluxo_acao.timestamp
```

If there is a need for only one of the subtypes (and don't need the column `ordem`) you can just query the individual table directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `ordem` it's a specific info for the system. And user can reorder things. But lets say that i want to select all the entries in the three tables from `fluxo` how can i do this with `joins`.  After addind this other pk in `fluxo_acao`?